# SQL Distinct Multiple Query Combine

Tags: mysql

I need to get information from two tables as you can see below but by shift so currently they are running basically the same query 4 times, 2 times for each shift. 
For first shift they grab all carton numbers that are NOT EQUAL to DELC and the second query for all cartons EQUAL to DELC. The problem is we want distinct carton numbers and if the carton was half processed on first shift and finished on second shift, even though we are doing distinct the carton shows up twice because its only distinct for each query.

Is there a way to run ALL 4 queries  together and do a distinct over the entire data?

```
1 Day old 1st shift = DELC
select count(distinct a.Barcode)
from [RL_Ship].[dbo].[mSCAN] as a inner join  
[RL_Ship].dbo].wmsInboundQueue] on
a.barcode = substring(message,26,20)
Where BagToteFlag = 'Y' and direction = 'Send'
and timeStamp >= '2016-06-14 03:00:00' 
and timeStamp < '2016-06-14    15:00:00' 
and substring(message,64,4) = 'DELC'
and SUBSTRING(rawdata,21,20) > '0'

1 Day old 1st shift <> DELC
select count(distinct a.Barcode)
from [RL_Ship].[dbo].[mSCAN] as a inner join    
[RL_Ship].dbo].wmsInboundQueue] on
a.barcode = substring(message,26,20) 
Where a.BagToteFlag = 'Y' and a.direction = 'Send' 
and a.timeStamp >= '2016-06-14 03:00:00'
and a.timeStamp < '2016-06-14 15:00:00'
and substring(message,64,4) <> 'DELC'
and SUBSTRING(rawdata,21,20) > '0'

1 Day old 2nd shift = DELC
select count(distinct a.Barcode)
from [RL_Ship].[dbo].[mSCAN] as a inner join [RL_Ship].[dbo].
[wmsInboundQueue] on
a.barcode = substring(message,26,20) 
Where a.BagToteFlag = 'Y' and a.direction = 'Send' 
and a.timeStamp >= '2016-06-14 15:00:00' 
and a.timeStamp < '2016-06-15 03:00:00'
and substring(message,64,4) = 'DELC'
and SUBSTRING(rawdata,21,20) > '0'

1 Day old 2nd shift <> DELC
select count(distinct a.Barcode)
from [RL_Ship].[dbo].[mSCAN] as a inner join [RL_Ship].[dbo].
[wmsInboundQueue] on
a.barcode = substring(message,26,20)
Where a.BagToteFlag = 'Y' and a.direction = 'Send'
and a.timeStamp >= '2016-06-14 15:00:00' 
and a.timeStamp < '2016-06-15 03:00:00' 
and substring(message,64,4) <> 'DELC'
and SUBSTRING(rawdata,21,20) > '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correct the first query I would have tried to get the result you want is something like

```
SELECT count(distinct barcode)  FROM (
select distinct a.Barcode <rest of query>
UNION
select distinct a.Barcode <rest of next query>
UNION ... )
```

Comment: Though you don't need the outer select as UNION does a distinct, union all would retain all the results.

Comment: Yeah but will that give me a unique count of each query? I need to get a number/count for each of the 4 separate queries listed. But as I stated if there is a barcode in the first query I don't want that counted in say the second query if the barcode shows up in that data.

Answer (score 0):

If I do a union and take off the count part I get the correct number as the duplicates are removed across ALL queries, but if I do a union and a count the number is off, it doesn't remove the duplicates.......

and I actually need a total count per query as they are different shifts/time ranges.

The answer of doing a count and then from is good but one I couldn't get that to work and 2 I think that is only going to give me a count off ALL right?

I tried the following but it gave me the following error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

EDIT: Ok I got this working by adding 'as table1' at the end but as I suspected it is only giving me a total, but without duplicates, which is great but I need a count for each of the 4 queries. Any ideas on that?

```
select count(distinct Barcode) from
(select distinct a.barcode
from [RL_Ship].[dbo].[mSCAN] as a inner join [RL_Ship].[dbo].
[wmsInboundQueue] on
a.barcode = substring(message,26,20)
Where BagToteFlag = 'Y' and direction = 'Send'
and timeStamp >= '2016-06-14 03:00:00' and timeStamp < '2016-06-14
15:00:00' 
and substring(message,64,4) = 'DELC'
and SUBSTRING(rawdata,21,20) > '0'
union
select distinct a.Barcode
from [RL_Ship].[dbo].[mSCAN] as a inner join [RL_Ship].[dbo].
[wmsInboundQueue] on
a.barcode = substring(message,26,20) 
Where a.BagToteFlag = 'Y' and a.direction = 'Send' 
and a.timeStamp >= '2016-06-14 03:00:00'
and a.timeStamp < '2016-06-14 15:00:00'
and substring(message,64,4) <> 'DELC'
and SUBSTRING(rawdata,21,20) > '0'
union
select distinct a.Barcode
from [RL_Ship].[dbo].[mSCAN] as a inner join [RL_Ship].[dbo].
[wmsInboundQueue] on
a.barcode = substring(message,26,20) 
Where a.BagToteFlag = 'Y' and a.direction = 'Send' 
and a.timeStamp >= '2016-06-14 15:00:00' 
and a.timeStamp < '2016-06-15 03:00:00'
and substring(message,64,4) = 'DELC'
and SUBSTRING(rawdata,21,20) > '0'
union
select distinct a.Barcode
from [RL_Ship].[dbo].[mSCAN] as a inner join [RL_Ship].[dbo].
[wmsInboundQueue] on
a.barcode = substring(message,26,20)
Where a.BagToteFlag = 'Y' and a.direction = 'Send'
and a.timeStamp >= '2016-06-14 15:00:00' 
and a.timeStamp < '2016-06-15 03:00:00' 
and substring(message,64,4) <> 'DELC'
and SUBSTRING(rawdata,21,20) > '0')
```